# Binding Image from bytes in listview (Windows phone 8.1)

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing my first windows phone 8.1 app. I need to bind an image in a list view. the image is in **bytes[]** format. I have already converted to a **Bitmap** image using this function

```
public async Task<BitmapImage> GetImageFromByteArray(string s_FileName)
    {
        using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream raStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(raStream))
            {
                byte[] data = await GetImageBytes(s_FileName);
                writer.WriteBytes(data);
                await writer.StoreAsync();
                await writer.FlushAsync();
                writer.DetachStream();
            }

            raStream.Seek(0);
            BitmapImage bitMapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitMapImage.SetSource(raStream);
            return bitMapImage;
        }
    }
```

now i need to bind this image to an image control in a listview item.

Here is my XAML Code. the image control name is (**img_test**)

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="lst_Test" Background="White" Foreground="Black" SelectionChanged="lst_BestDrivers_SelectionChanged" Margin="10">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemsTest">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" />
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" />

        <Image x:Name="img_test" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="10,10,10,10" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Icons/Icon1png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="ItemsTest"/>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
Here is what is done to clarify more:

1- I use the Image Filename to get an array of bytes using a remote web service.

2- I use the returned `bytes[]` to get a `bitmap` object.

How can I use this array or the bitmap for binding?
I tried the sample in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259469/windows-phone-8-load-byte-array-into-xaml-image-with-binding) , but it did not work for me because the calling of the web service requires an `async` call which is not possible after implementing the `IValueConverter` interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after digging and see many samples here in **stackoverflow** and other sites, I have to solve the `async` problem. It is solved using the `TaskCompletionNotifier` class in **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003827/async-implementation-of-ivalueconverter/15007717#15007717)** which allows me to make `async` calls while implementing the `ivalueconverter` interface. using the above function to get the bitmap image from the `bytes` array.

all what i need to do is

```
    public class BytesToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream raStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            return new TaskCompletionNotifier<BitmapImage>(GetImageFromByteArray((String)value));
        }
    }
}
```

Also, i need to add a static resource using this

```
xmlns:Global="using:MYNAMESPACE"
<Page.Resources>
    <Global:BytesToImageConverter x:Key="LocalImageConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
```

the class `BytesToImageConverter` is the one implementing the `ivalueconverter` interface.

now, use the resource to bind the image

```
<Image DataContext="{Binding PhotoPath, Converter={StaticResource LocalImageConverter}}" 
               x:Name="img_test" 
               Source="{Binding Result}"
               Grid.Column="0" 
               Grid.RowSpan="3" 
               Margin="10,10,10,10" 
               Width="90"
               Height="90"
               Stretch="Fill"/>
```

the source is bound to `Result`

this will do the trick.

thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your BitmapImage in a property, ready for binding. You can just Bind the Image Source to the BitmapImage

```
<Image x:Name="img_test" Source="{Binding MyBitmapImage}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="10,10,10,10" />
```

If you don't have your BitmapImage in a property, then you should just set the source of the object

```
img_test.Source = myBitmapImage
```

Comment: i do not have it in a property, all what i have is just the filename in the data source which i use to get a bitmap object.

Comment: edited without property. however this is not really a binding

Comment: it is a part of a listview item; how can i do that?